# Regex in MongoDB's $cond or $switch condition expression?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For a  collection like this

```
{ _id: 1, name: "novel_1", qty: 15}
{ _id: 2, name: "magazine_1", qty: 5}
{ _id: 3, name: "novel_2", qty: 5}
{ _id: 4, name: "guitar_1", qty: 10}
{ _id: 5, name: "violin_1", qty: 10}
```

I want to somehow categorize the items based on its name using the $project pipeline. And then get a group-by count out of it.

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$project: {category: {
        $switch: {
            branches: [
                // use regex here to categorize the items by their name
                {case: {$in: ['$name', [/magazine/, /novel/]]},
                    then: 'book'},
                {case: {$in: ['$name', [/guitar/, /violin/]]},
                    then: 'instrument'}
            ],
            default: 'others'
        }
    }}},
    // get the group-by count based on the category
    {$group: {
        _id: {category: '$category'},
        count: {$sum: '$qty'}
    }}
]);
```

However it seems like MongoDB doesn't support the regex condition expression in $project pipeline. So how can we do this transform-then-group-by query? I guess one way to do it is via the MapReduce, but it is said the performance is not great. Especially I am using python for my app, using MapReduce will tangle the JS code and python code together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need *MapReduce*. You can use the Aggregation Framework to do this.

Also note that you don't need to first `$project` your documents, you can pass the `$switch` expression to `_id`

```
db.items.aggregate(
    [
       {
          "$group": {
             "_id": {
                "$switch": {
                   "branches": [
                      {
                         "case": {
                            "$or": [
                               {
                                  "$gt": [
                                     {
                                        "$indexOfCP": [
                                           "$name",
                                           "magazine"
                                        ]
                                     },
                                     -1
                                  ]
                               },
                               {
                                  "$gt": [
                                     {
                                        "$indexOfCP": [
                                           "$name",
                                           "novel"
                                        ]
                                     },
                                     -1
                                  ]
                               }
                            ]
                         },
                         "then": "book"
                      },
                      {
                         "case": {
                            "$or": [
                               {
                                  "$gt": [
                                     {
                                        "$indexOfCP": [
                                           "$name",
                                           "violin"
                                        ]
                                     },
                                     -1
                                  ]
                               },
                               {
                                  "$gt": [
                                     {
                                        "$indexOfCP": [
                                           "$name",
                                           "guitar"
                                        ]
                                     },
                                     -1
                                  ]
                               }
                            ]
                         },
                         "then": "instrument"
                      }
                   ],
                   "default": "others"
                }
             },
             "count":{"$sum": "$qty"}
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

---

```
db.items.aggregate(
    [
       {
          "$group": {
             "_id": {
                "$switch": {
                   "branches": [
                      {
                         "case": {
                            "$gt": [
                               {
                                  "$size": {
                                     "$setInterserction": [
                                        {
                                           "$split": [
                                              "$name",
                                              "-"
                                           ]
                                        },
                                        [
                                           "magazine",
                                           "novel"
                                        ]
                                     ]
                                  }
                               },
                               0
                            ]
                         },
                         "then": "book"
                      },
                      {
                         "case": {
                            "$gt": [
                               {
                                  "$size": {
                                     "$setInterserction": [
                                        {
                                           "$split": [
                                              "$name",
                                              "-"
                                           ]
                                        },
                                        [
                                           "guitar",
                                           "violin"
                                        ]
                                     ]
                                  }
                               },
                               0
                            ]
                         },
                         "then": "instrument"
                      }
                   ],
                   "default": "others"
                }
             },
             "count": {"$sum": "$qty"}
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This is a very useful aggregation technique.